# Парсить массивы из текстового файла

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Есть лог `log.txt` вида:

```
--------
    текст
    array{....}
    текст
    текст
--------
    array{....}
    текст
```

Как спарсить из этого лога массивы? То есть, чтобы на выходе было:

```
array{....}
array{....}
```

Пробую так:

```
$s = file_get_contents('log.txt');
$arr = explode("----------",$s);
foreach ($arr as $key => $val){

    $array = split('array', $val);
    echo "<pre>";
    echo $array;
    echo "</pre>";
}
```

Но вырезает только слово array, а мне нужно содержимое

Comment: А что вы уже попробовали?

Comment: Добавил в тему, что делаю

Answer (score 1, accepted):

выбрать нужные строки можно так:

```
$arrays = preg_grep('/\s+array{/', file('log.txt'));
```

Comment: Почему то здесь и в нижнем примере выводит пустой массив, в чем может быть дело?

Comment: сделайте `var_export(file('log.txt'));`и опубликуйте кусочек

Comment: я тоже, наверное еще не проснулся! Всё в порядке, просто я вместо фигурных скобок обычные указал!

Comment: бывает :) ну и славно

Comment: А тут фигурная скобка не должна закрывался в паттерне?

Comment: этот код отбирает элементы массива , совпадающие с образцом. поэтому достаточно минимального фрагмента, который определяет выбор

Comment: @ splash58 `$arrays = preg_grep('/\s+array(/', file('log.txt'));
print_r($arrays);` пишет ошибку `Warning: preg_grep() [function.preg-grep]: Compilation failed: missing ) at offset 9 in lod.php on line 1`

Comment: код из второго ответа выберет сразу описание массива, это хорошо. НО если лог большой, то regex на нем будет работать очень долго, поэтому я предложил этот код, который отберет побстрее нужные строки, а потом все равно вам придется их обработать, чтобы удалить лишнее

Comment: Понял, спасибо!

Comment: так у вас опять круглая скобка

Comment: мне и нужна круглая, в логе круглая

Comment: тогда надо поставить обратный слэш перед скобкой `\(` И кcтати, патерн в выбранном ответе поменяйте от греха на `/array\([^\)]+\)/`

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38121/discussion-between--and-splash58).

Answer (score 1):

Пожалуйста:

```
$s = file_get_contents('log.txt');

// Работает в PHP 5.2.2 и старше.
preg_match_all('/array{.+}/', $s, $matches);

print_r($matches);
```

[Пример онлайн](http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/fgn).

Comment: как минимум, добавьте `g` после патерна

Comment: наверное лучше просто использовать `preg_match_all`, спасибо